# How to Access Grouped List in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am facing issue in list,
i have a grouped list

and i get a response from JSON web service that's working fine but the problem is how i can get specific element from first list index

```
    private class RootObject
    {
        public string flag { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }
    private class Result
    {

        public List<List<string>> Professions { get; set; }

    }
```

and i am getting response

```
void onResponse(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            onLoadingStope(sender, e);
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
            string flag = rootObject.flag;
            string msg = rootObject.message;
            if (flag.Equals("1"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success message - " + msg);


                foreach (var temp in e.Result)
                {

                    list_professions.ItemsSource = rootObject.result.Professions;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error message - " + msg);
                MessageBox.Show("Oops! response : " + msg);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

UI

```
 <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="list_professions" Tap="list_professions_Tap" IsGroupingEnabled="True" ></toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please add your binding code both C# and XAML so that we can know where in binding you are facing problem

Comment: If you post complete code we can try to help.

Comment: Hi Pawan & Jerin Sir Please check my updated code

Comment: Can you plas provide a sample JSON and let us know what you want to get printed?

Comment: The output i am getting from JSON and Showing LongListMultiSelector  is fine now i want when user will Tap a particular index item i want to show all the elements for that index in another page list box ..

Answer (score 0):

For accessing first group items its going to be

```
list_professions.Source= rootObject.result.Professions[0];
```

**EDIT**
According to your edit now you need to get on tap event the index of clicked item then inside your code the second list should be populated using that index.

Try this

```
foreach(string temp in rootobject.result.Professions[0])
{
  console.Writeline(temp);
}
```

Comment: Hello Jerin sir  list_professions.ItemsSource = rootObject.result.Professions[0]; this is not working

Comment: actually i have a grouped list something like first main list index start like [0] to [100] and second list like[0][1][2] and i want to access second list item through first list index\

Comment: yes sir you are right now the question is how i can access second list item through first list index?

Comment: The way that you can access is using the index rootObject.result.Professions[0]
but the problem is your  current LongListMultiSelector is expecting a list of string which contains its sublist of string so you cant set it but you would need to set it as a source of list of string lists

Comment: sir the code i have updated is working fine now i want to access second list item through first list index

Comment: You can get each substring of first item if you use the edit.

Comment: sir when my page load i have to show all the sub list item in listbox thats ok now i want to access sublist item through first list index

Comment: Isnt the foreach statement working? What does your console output show?

Comment: Whats happening when you are using the foreach statememnt it should print the string list. Also please add a sample JSON so that we can check if we are getting correct value

Comment: So if its showing then thats your question is solved I belive all you need to do is on selection you need to find the index of clicked item and you can get its list.

Comment: same thing i want sir when user will tap a particular item i want to access that item index and related second list item value

Comment: Are you able to get the index of that item?